# Node.js MySQL Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Здравствуйте! Запускаю backend проекта на Node Express, Angular и получаю ошибку: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'пароль',
   database: 'имябазы',
    insecureAuth: true
});
connection.connect(function(err, callback) {
//if (err) {  console.log(err); process.exit(1); }
});
var database = {};

database.executeQuery = function(query, values, callback) {
    connection.query(query, values, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            callback(null, rows, fields);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
};
database.escapeValue = function(value) {
   return connection.escape(value);
}
module.exports = database;
```

Comment: База данных создавалась в ручную по запросам!

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что запрос не может выполниться так как произошёл некий fatal error. Попробуйте разобраться что это за fatal error был.